# How to password protect an individual file?

Tags: ubuntu, security, unix, passwords, password-protection

I use digitalocean, and all my files are in `/var/www/html/`, so, say, if I have a file `/var/www/html/index_test.php` how can I password protect the individual file as simply and securely as possible. It doesn't need to be HIPAA or Bank Record - level secure. I've used `htpasswd` before to modify the htaccess file and add a user, but, having just learned this, I'm only aware of it being able to password protect *directories* not *individual files*.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess), you can protect individual files. You have to make sure you use the `.htaccess` file in the directory where the file is located (you can't put it in a directory higher up the tree).

```
<Files "log.txt">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
# Basic auth stuff here
</Files>
```